# Configuring a basic multisite development environment in Linux

Tags: 7, commerce, multi-sites

While installing Multisite devlopment i followed below instructions    https://www.drupal.org/node/823990#comment-10184088

When i trying to call http://testsite.localhost/install.php throwing error Forrbidden Access to Page and in apache2/errorlog its showing AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/drupal/sites/testsite.localhost/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer:

Answer (score 1):

If you followed the exact instructions and you did not change any paths, then you have a typo: /var/www/**html**/drupal/sites/testsite.localhost/ See the extra 'html' directory? Make sure the paths in the apache config (step#3) match the actual paths in your file system.